# Textarea jquery cannot hold what I have typed in

Tags: jquery, textarea

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".comment").click(function(){

var element = $(this);
var id = element.attr("post_id");

$("#"+id).html('<form action="test.php" method="post"><textarea name="body" id="body_'+id+'"></textarea></form>');  

$("#body_"+id).focus();

return false;   

});
});
```

```
<a href="#" post_id="17" class="comment">Open</a>
<div id="17"></div>
```

Why each time after I type something in the textarea and click .comment link, the value of textarea becomes blank, how should I keep what I typed to be not removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting whatever html you have inside the div with this line...

```
$("#"+id).html('<form action="test.php" method="post"><textarea name="body" id="body_'+id+'"></textarea></form>');
```

try changing it into this:

```
var textArea = $("#body_"+id);
var textAreaValue = textArea.length > 0 ? textArea.val() : '';
$("#"+id).html('<form action="test.php" method="post"><textarea name="body" id="body_'+id+'">'+textAreaValue+'</textarea></form>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent default behaviour of link otherwise the page is reloaded:

```
$(".comment").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```